# How can I understand/detect/correct this pasting issue in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf

I have encountered some strange behavior pasting certain text into Microsoft Word 2016.  If I paste page 21 of [this document](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15859-f01/www/notes/comb.pdf) into Word, all of the text between the first two instances of the < (not ≤) character on that page is replaced by a single < character.  Similarly weird behavior occurs around other <.  If I paste and Keep Text Only, the missing text appears, but my purpose for pasting into Word is to alter the formatting in such a way that my [TTS reader](https://ttsreader.com/player/) puts pauses in desirable places, and Keep Text Only reinserts unwanted line breaks.  Using paste and Keep Text Only, then replacing all ^p with a single space mostly solves the problem, with only the occasional undiagnosed strange behavior remaining.

Why does this behavior occur, and is there a more targeted workaround than using Keep Text Only when pasting a document which may contain many such instances?

Comment: I don't know.  I think it is widely different formatting. What I do in this case is as follows:    Make a blank space in the target document (2 or 3 blank lines will do). Copy from the source document and paste all starting in the blank space. That should work.  Now blend your changes in the target document.

Comment: This could be a character set conflict. It could be where you are pasting from has different character formatting than where you are pasting to. In general, modern systems try retain character encoding and formatting on copied text. I personally find it immensely annoying.

Comment: Pasting from pdf using anything other than text only will lead to formatting anomalies. Also, if the pdf is the result of an OCR process, you can get *strange* text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I investigated this particular case, copying everything on the PDF page except the page number at the bottom (I - 21). I am using the current version of Word in Office 365 on Windows 11.

My best guess is that this particular copy is going wrong because the program you are copying from is creating an HTML format "clip" on the clipboard that does not encode the `<` characters properly, but just leaves `<` in the HTML text rather than encoding it using the standard "escape", i.e. `&lt;` .

Here, that happens if I open the PDF in Microsoft Edge, but it might happen in other browsers too, e.g. the older Internet Explorer.

I cannot find any settings in Edge that would change this behaviour (although it is also possible that Edge normally works fine but something like my virus checker changes the data).

i.e., to *fix* this problem you would have to open your PDFs in something that produces at least correct HTML, and preferably something better. Here, I had the best *formatted* results by opening the PDF in the free version of Adobe Acrobat, but even if that is a possibility for you, you will need to check whether it does anything like what you need. Alternatively, if you only need plain text, it might be easier to Paste->Special and use the Unicode Text option, every time.

Edge puts a small number of formats on the clipboard (Essentially Unicode Text, Text and HTML). The HTML that Word gets from the Clipboard starts like this - I have used `@@@` sequences where I can't reproduce encoded bytes exactly as in the source data:

```
Version:0.9
StartHTML:0000000105
EndHTML:0000003438
StartFragment:0000000141
EndFragment:0000003402
<html>
<body>
<!--StartFragment-->Theorem 2. If gi is the Sprague-Grundy function of Gi, i = 1,...,n, then G = G1 +
@@@ + Gn has Sprague-Grundy function g(x1,...,xn) = g1(x1) @@@ gn(xn).
Proof. Let x = (x1,...,xn) be an arbitrary point of X. Let b = g1(x1)@@@gn(xn).
We are to show two things for the function g(x1,...,xn):
(1) For every non-negative integer a<b, there is a follower
```

The first 5 lines form a header that describes the format and indicates where the actual data starts and how long it is. The next line starts with the standard `<html>` keyword, but there is nothing like normal HTML markup inside the `<body>` . You may also notice that in the PDF, there is space either side of the `<` sign in the `a < b` expression but in this "HTML" there is just `a<b`. That probably means that the original document used an automatic mechanism to add space either side of a `<` in a math expression (both LaTeX and Word would do that), and that whatever produced the PDF positioned the characters to reflect that, rather than adding spaces.

So when Word pastes that, it is probably interpreting the `<` as the beginning of an HTML opening element tag, then misinterprets everything it reads until it reaches something that tells it to stop - probably the next `<` character.

If instead I open the page in FireFox, and copy it to the clipboard, it posts a rather different set of formats, but I think Word will still pick up the HTML one. It starts like this:

```
Version:0.9
StartHTML:00000182
EndHTML:00096939
StartFragment:00000216
EndFragment:00096903
SourceURL:https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15859-f01/www/notes/comb.pdf
<html><body>
<!--StartFragment--><div class="canvasWrapper"></div><div class="textLayer" style="width: round(var(--scale-factor) * 612px, 1px); height: round(var(--scale-factor) * 792px, 1px);" data-main-rotation="0"><span style="left: 11.76%; top: 9.38%;
```

You can probably tell that the HTML chunk is much longer (compare the values of EndHTML or EndFragment) and that it actually appears to be "proper" HTML. The encoding of the part with `a<b` in it looks like this:

```
<span style="left: 54.78%; top: 17.77%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*11.96px); font-family: sans-serif; transform: scaleX(1.23868);" role="presentation" dir="ltr" class="">a &lt; b\</span>\<span style="left: 60.23%; top: 17.77%; font-size: calc(var(--scale-factor)*11.96px); font-family: serif; transform: scaleX(1.167);" role="presentation" dir="ltr">, there is a follower
```

i.e. it encodes `a<b` as `a &lt; b` which Word seems to interpret the way that you might hope.

The reason why I found using Adobe Acrobat seemed best for importing the correct formatting is that it copies the text+formatting in RTF rather than HTML, and it seems like a higher quality rendering than the HTML ones.

I didn't look at whether this is a well-known problem with Edge, but I do find it strange that it would get something like that as wrong as it does.